# Xcode 14 how to open two different (playgound) files within the same window (under two different tabs)?

Tags: navigation, xcode14

I newly installed the latest Xcode 14.3.1. And have encountered a navigational problem.

There are two different playground files I want to have open. After I open the 1st one, when I hit cmd+o to open the 2nd one, it opens into a new 2nd window. But I don't want two windows, I want just one with two tabs. That seems impossible?

I have tried to Google search, and tried different navigational settings as well as menu options. Nothing seems to work. When I read the Xcode documentation, I can't quite find as a definitive simple answer as to whether I can, or can not, open two files in the same window.

What am I missing? Please help. Thank you.